# redirect to default

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

there are: webpages

for example:

```
url/willpower/default.aspx
```

---

```
url/willpower/purchase_order.aspx
url/willpower/movement.aspx
```

How to make -
e.g if user goes by url -

```
 http://<machine_name>:<port>/willpower/movement.aspx
```

(It prints some error --> "You don't have permission to view via direct link.")

Then, In 5 seconds, it redirects the user to `default.aspx`.

with regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript setTimeOut

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location="Default.aspx" }, 5000);
```

Comment: How to block the `Url` then?? :)

Comment: Thanks Teddy for the answer.It solves my issue on half. What about the url - i mean e.g if i want to access the page (~/willpower/movemement.aspx) via direct link - it shows me message like: 'You don't have permission to view content via direct link. You will be redirected.'

Comment: @BulatMakhmutov What's the normal way to access this page?

Comment: narmal way to access this page - via Default.aspx, not via direct link

Comment: @BulatMakhmutov How it goes to this page from default.aspx, for example server.transfer, or redirect using a query string parameter?

Comment: default.aspx has buttons like:

`<table cellspacing="20px">
        <tr>
            <td><button  onclick="window.location='manufacturer.aspx'">Manufacturer</button></td>
            <td><button  onclick="window.location='purchase_order.aspx'">Purchase Order</button></td>
            <td><button  onclick="window.location='movement.aspx'">Movemement</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>`

Comment: Guys, thanks very much for help. Succeeded to do that.

Comment: @BulatMakhmutov I tried your html codes above and patil.rahulk 's solution works fine. You can check network traffic to see if there's a  param "Referer" in request header when you redirect from default to movement page

Answer (score 1):

The redirection part is answered by @teddy. For the first part, You can set use the server variable called `Request.UrlReferrer` this will give you where the request for current page came from. If it has not come from the page you want (i guess you want every page to be accessed from default.aspx), then once this check fails in page_load, display the message 'You don't have permission to view content via direct link. You will be redirected.' and set the redirection using code given by @teddy.

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer is not working correctly or i do something wrong. Because Request.UrlReferrer in any case gives NULL value, if even i went from other page.

Comment: how are you moving from one page to another page? response.redirect?